# lambda - can't compare datetime.date to int

Tags: python, django, lambda

I am sorting multiple querysets from multiple models.

```
bs = Book.objects.filter(person=person).order_by('-release_date') 
jn = Journal.objects.filter(person=person).order_by('-year') 
np = Newspaper.objects.filter(person=person).order_by('-year')
```

the problem is that `Book` has `release_date`-Attribute as Integer, `Journal` has its `year` as DateTimeField and `Newspaper` has its `year` as Integer.

I did this to sort them:

```
joined = itertools.chain(bs, jn, np)
sorter = lambda x: x.release_date if hasattr(x,'release_date') else x.year
latest_pubs = sorted(joined, key = sorter, reverse=True)
```

but it is saying:

```
can't compare datetime.date to int
```

The thing is that I dont want to change `year`-format of Newspaper to DateTimeField. How can I sort them in this case?

Comment: You can take a `year` from `release_date`: `x.release_date.year`.

Comment: @alecxe would ``x.release_date.year`` be then ``Integer``?

Comment: Yup, just give it a try.

Comment: @alecxe oh sorry, i wrote wrong description. Book has the ``release_date`` as Integer, Journal as DateTimeField and Newspaper as Integer. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the `sorter` function and take a [`year`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.year) from `datetime` fields:

```
def sorter(x):
    if hasattr(x, 'year'):
        if isinstance(x.year, datetime):
            return x.year.year
        else:
            return x.year
    else:
        return x.release_date
```

Comment: @doniyor nice! Just consider following the [naming best practices](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). You've even mixed up things yourself :)

Comment: yeah you are right. wrong names are messing me up right now! thanks bro